# Rails - Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Must provide source or customer.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

I'm building an application (based in online resource). You can sign up or login with devise. Then, you can buy a product. Or make your own list and sell your products.

I'm integrating Stripe. When I create the Charge, I get this error in the console: `Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Must provide source or customer.)`.

Here is the code of the orders_controller.rb for the charge action:

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
token = params[:stripeToken]

begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => (@listing.price * 100).floor,
    :currency => "usd",
    :card => token
    )
  flash[:notice] = "Thanks for ordering!"
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:danger] = e.message
end
```

Of course I'm taking a look in the Stripe API Documentation here: [Charge documentation example](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges) and here: [Charge full API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges)

I'm not sure how to handle the `:resource` or `customer`. I saw in other materials in the web that some people create a customer. In other sites it says that the `:card` is deprecated, so I'm a little confused.

I will leave the github repository of my project, and feel free to take a look. I'm trying to deal with Transfers and Recipients too. [Project Repository](https://github.com/carlos99/etsonia)

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), stripe expects either customer or source to be mentioned while creating a charge. So, you either need to

- Create a customer on stripe(if you want to charge that customer in future too) from the token you received, and mention that customer while creating a charge,

  ```
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(source: params[:stripeToken])

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
    :amount => 400,
    :currency => "usd",
    :customer => customer.id,
    :description => "Charge for test@example.com"
  })
  ```
- Or, if you don't want to create a customer, then directly mention received token as a source,

  ```
  Stripe::Charge.create({
    :amount => 400,
    :currency => "usd",
    :source => params[:stripeToken],
    :description => "Charge for test@example.com"
  })
  ```

Comment: Thank you. You are rigth. But now I just have another error: `stripe::invalidrequesterror (can't transfer to a recipient that has no default payment account.)`

I take a look in the documentation. The process for my app is this:

User Sing Up. Then, you create a new product and when you are creating this product, you add your bank account information. 

Then, we you add your account, you are able to purchase.

Comment: By looking at the error, seems like you are transferring funds to some  recipient. What account number you are using for transfer ?
Did you checked [testing](https://stripe.com/docs/testing) section in Stripe documentation, which has test account numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone going through the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide), you may have something like this (using an existing account)

```rb
account_links = Stripe::AccountLink.create({
  account: 'acct_1032D82eZvKYlo2C',
  refresh_url: 'https://example.com/reauth',
  return_url: 'https://example.com/return',
  type: 'account_onboarding',
})
```

if so, just change it to look like this (i.e. include the actual `account.id` you created in the previous step):

```rb
account_links = Stripe::AccountLink.create({
  account: account.id,
  refresh_url: 'https://example.com/reauth',
  return_url: 'https://example.com/return',
  type: 'account_onboarding',
})
```